# JavaScript Asynchronous Design Book?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

Can anyone recommend a really advanced book on asynchronous programming in JavaScript?  Something that assumes the reader already knows how to do things in JavaScript, but is looking for in-depth analysis on finding the best way.  Something that's not about performance tweaks and hacks, but a serious book on architecture.

What I'm looking for would go into things like queueing asynchronous actions, unifying error handling between regular synchronous exceptions and onError asynchronous callbacks, chaining asynchronous calls while ensuring cleanup operations required by the original call occur, etc.  And the question of how to best manage state when 10 Ajax requests are running at the same time could be a book in itself.

Outside of JavaScript books, any recommendations for a favorite book on such patterns in general?

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend [Ajax Patterns and Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596161) along with the other books recommended. [RESTful Web Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260) also describes how to introduce loose coupling between the client and server; as well the reasons to why all requests to the server should be stateless.

Comment: Ajax Patterns and Best Practices looks like the best recommended so far.  As an aside, when I mentioned the issue of managing state, I meant the state in JavaScript on the client, not on the server.  Going without state (other than authentication, cache, and a few other exceptions like random tokens to include with posts) on the server-side is pretty much a given as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: ok, well that is usually taken care of by your javascript code. WRT the client state when it talks to the server, that is determined with the XHR request that your JS performs - the request's URI and body should contain all of the state that the server needs to determine what to send back. If this is what you are looking for, RESTful Web Services talks all about it.

Comment: Part which is "usually taken care of by your javascript code" is the part that I'm finding to be very complex.  Patterns of wrapped closures build up as I proceed through Ajax calls.  One call has an onSuccess and an onFailure, but after it completes, another Ajax call may be made which has an onSuccess/onFailure which wraps the previous onSuccess/onFailure with some extra code, etc.  Makes for ugly code with many try/catch blocks.  There are also patterns that are variations of a task queue.  Winding up writing an infrastructure for all this as a tier between jQuery Ajax and app.

Comment: You're right in that the code quickly becomes complex.  If you are trying to use jQuery as the framework in which to build your web app, i would recommend to not do this.  It's ok to use it as one of your libraries, but not as its base - it was not designed for complicated web apps. JavascriptMVC is a good framework if you have a large codebase built with jQuery.  I personally recommend dojo as great toolkit to create modular widgets, offers all the capabilities of jQUery, a dependency manger, and more.

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101800) is quite a good book. It's a bit dated and the javascript code style is not to my liking but the techniques and design patterns themselves are still highly relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I'd second Ajax Design Patterns.  Also from O'Reilly, and a little more current: [Even Faster Web Sites](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596522315/).  Not apparent from the title, but this one covers a lot of advanced Ajax/asynchronous techniques.